# SQL/PHP Unsure how to use If against 2 where operators

Tags: php, sql, if-statement

so i've connected to my DB in PHP via SQL.

To load certain parts of pages I've added a field on the database for 'betaaccount', if the value is a 1 the page objects should load, if it is not, then the else statement will load regular page objects.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tz_members WHERE alias = '$_SESSION[user]' &&     betaccount = '1'");

if ($_SESSION['user'] == $result)  {
    include 'support_beta_content.php';
    include 'footer.php';
} else {
    include 'support_content.php';
    include 'footer.php';
}
```

I'm still new to this, I'm not using PDO as I'm only doing this locally and experimenting, just trying to get an idea of how to get this working. Thanks.

Comment: its always 1 sine you added it explicetly also the result variable is mysqli object, not a fetched result, you need to fetch it and compare to $row['betaaccount']

Comment: The first step to debug such thing is to dump the value (`$result` in this case) and tripple check if it really holds what you expect... (it does not in this case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of things in your code that suggest you're learning PHP/MySQL; I'd recommend you find a few tutorials to help in the process, and follow them.

Firstly, as @mishik writes, your SQL query is probably invalid.

Secondly, if field betaacount is a numerical datatype, you should leave off the quotes (`AND betaccount = 1`).

Next, as @Kelu Thatsall writes (as well as a comment), the $result variable doesn't hold the output of the query - it's a handle to the results. Logically, you might decide that if you get 1 row back, the user is a beta user, otherwise they aren't, in which case the code becomes

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT 1 FROM tz_members WHERE alias = '$_SESSION[user]' and     betaccount = '1'");

if (1 == $result->num_rows)  {
    include 'support_beta_content.php';
    include 'footer.php';
} else {
    include 'support_content.php';
    include 'footer.php';
}
```

This transfers slightly different data between the database and PHP script, which is a tiny bit more efficient.

Finally, please tell me you know about SQL injection - `$_SESSION['user']` is properly escaped, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Corrent syntax for such SQL query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tz_members
WHERE  alias = '$_SESSION[user]' 
       AND betaccount = '1'
```

Instead of `||` and `&&` you need to use `OR` and `AND` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tz_members WHERE alias = '$_SESSION[user]' AND betaccount = '1'");

$user = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if ($_SESSION['user'] == $user['alias'])  {
    include 'support_beta_content.php';
    include 'footer.php';
} else {
    include 'support_content.php';
    include 'footer.php';
}
```

But better in this case just check if the result had any rows with mysqli_num_rows

Comment: Got it working!
Cheers guys, was a combination of just about everything you all said :)

Answer (score 0):

If alias contains unique values in your database you can try to only fetch the field betaccount of the current user and check if it is one.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT betaccount FROM tz_members WHERE alias = '{$_SESSION['user']}'");

$finfo = mysql_fetch_field($result)
 if($finfo->betacount == 1){
    include 'support_beta_content.php';
    include 'footer.php';
  }
else
  {
  include 'support_content.php';
  include 'footer.php';
  }
```

For mysql_fetch_field see [here][1]
[1]: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php